# when user click on next button then only next tab will appear on screen along with previous tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function () {

   var $tabs = $("#tabs");
   $tabs.tabs();
   $tabs.tabs("option", 'disabled', [1, 2, 3]);

   function getSelectedTabIndex() {
      return $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
      return $tabs.tabs('enable', $tabs);
      return $tabs.tabs('option', 'actaive',$tabs);
   }

   $("#goNext").click(function () {         
      var b = getSelectedTabIndex() + 1;
      $tabs.tabs('enable',b);
      $tabs.tabs('option', 'active', b);
      $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected', b);
   });
});
```

My code goes in correct way but only the problem is when user click on next button my previous is going to hide it should not be happen, when user click on next button next tab will be visible along with previous tab please tell me the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
function getSelectedTabIndex() {
    //1.8
    return $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
    //Code below is unreachable
    return $tabs.tabs('enable', $tabs);
    return $tabs.tabs('option', 'actaive',$tabs);
}
```

to

```
function getSelectedTabIndex() {
   return $tabs.tabs('option', 'active');
}
```

Each method should do only one task and do it correctly.  If you are trying to do more changes then find a better place other than `getSelectedTabIndex()`

Answer (score 0):

```
  return $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
  return $tabs.tabs('enable', $tabs);  // This will not called ever
  return $tabs.tabs('option', 'actaive',$tabs); // This will not called ever
```

for more please post some html or create fiddle please.

Answer (score 0):

set globle variable to store a current tab index

```
var currTabIndex // globle variable

$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
     collapsible: false,
     activate: function( event, ui ) {
         currTabIndex = ui.newTab.index();
     }
});
```

In the click event of next button

```
$("#goNext").click(function () {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", currTabIndex + 1 );
});
```

Comment: hey..! you have to upgrade your jquery-ui
here working link http://jsfiddle.net/bGpyt/1/

Comment: ok sir... but still one problem in your code, tabs are not disabled... i want all tabs are disabled they only appears when user click on next button.

Comment: Hello 

try this http://jsfiddle.net/bGpyt/2/

if you have predefined tab than you can put static like i had but if not you have do dynamic logic through a loop.